# How to bind two arrays to datagrid in WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf

I am new in programming.  I have a question about data biding in WPF.

I have two double arrays and would like to bind them to datagrid with two columns like:

-double[] acce goes to a column in datagridview with a header of "Acceleration"

-double[] peri goes to a column in datagridview with a header of "Period"

I googled this issue but could not find out the right one.  An example showing how will be greatly appreciated.  Thanks,

Comment: You might consider making a "state class" that contains those values for each measurement.  Then making a `List` or better an [`observable collection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604(v=vs.110).aspx) of the objects.  Then bind them to a datagridview. I think trying to bind to an array of values may bring its own challenges.

Comment: It may be hard for me to imnplement this.  The answer below works for me.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that; you have to bind to one object. You could create a a double[,] array (i.e. a 2D array) and copy acce into one column ([0, x]) and peri into the other ([1, x]) and bind to this new array:

```
double[,] combined = new double[2, acce.Length];
for (int i = 0; i < acce.Length; i++)
{
    combined[0, i] = acce[i];
    combined[1, i] = peri[i];
}
```

..and then bind to combined. Or you get more ambitious (and possibly learn some more) and create a class as @FelixCastor suggested.

PS the code above assumes that peri and acce have the same length.